# drill down without using code

Tags: storyboard, tableview, drilldown

I am quite new to xcode and app production. I have just finished watching a youtube video which uses storyboard to drill down without using any code. It involves using several Tableview controllers and creating a segue between tableview controllers to move between one another.

I have a two questions regarding this method.

Will apple accept my app using this technique?

What are the downsides to using this technique rather then doing it the traditional way?

here is the link to the video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYm3UH5rQtE

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storyboard and segue methods are provided by Apple. Your app will not get rejected because this option to use storyboard and segues are provided by Apple himself.

You can find out the opinions about the pros and cons using the storyboard or interface builder in a lot of places. One of them is here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder

Comment: I am personally finding storyboard alot easier to use. So easy in fact that I actually feel like I am cheating a little. It has made app production for amateurs like myself alot easier. For now I will stick to storyboards but I definitely should invest more time into understanding and learning the way to drill down using code.